# What are different between two ConstraintLayout for 4 image buttons in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I use *ConstraintLayout* in my Android project, I place four image buttons in the UI,  I hope the space between 4 image buttons are equal distance, it seems that both *Layout A* and *Layout B* can do that, you can see the result *Image AB*.

What are different between *Layout A* and *Layout B* ?

**Layout A**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_on" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnFlash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Layout B**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_on" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnFlash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image AB**

[image]

Comment: Constraint layout is setting up the view by putting constraint based on the reference to parent/surrounding sibling's.So both are correct based on ur need.

Comment: what is your question ?